# What is wrong with my code

Tags: java, recursion

Write a recursive, boolean -valued  method , containsVowel, that accepts a string  and returns true  if the string  contains a vowel. 
 A string  contains a vowel if: 
The first character  of the string  is a vowel, or 
The rest of the string  (beyond the first character ) contains a vowel 
This is for my Programing Lab
Here is what I have the complier sas that there is an error and it is not offering help.
Please Help me correct what is wrong thank you.

```
boolean containsVowel(String s)
{ 
    if(s.containsVowel("aeiouAEIOU")) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        (s.substring(!=));
        return false
    }
}
```

Compiler error(s)

codelab analysis

Remarks:
You seem to have an error in compilation

Here is another question that I did earlier:

Write a recursive, int -valued  method , len, that accepts a string  and returns the number of characters  in the string . 
 The length of a string  is: 
0 if the string  is the empty string  (""). 
1 more than the length of the rest of the string  beyond the first character.

Here is the answer My Programing Lab was looking for:

```
int len(String s)
{
if(s.equals("")){
    return 0;
}
 else {
return (1+len(s.substring(1)));}
}
```

Comment: Walk through your code as if you were the Java Virtual Machine, the JVM, and you'll see that if you got it to compile it would run forever.

Comment: What sort of compiler just says "there is an error"? Surely, it must say something of use.

Comment: so i need to say under the else portion that s !=aeiouAEIOU?

Comment: @AlorvaEx: that makes no sense. Post your actual error messages as an edit to your original post. Also please get rid of your ALL UPPERCASE comments as that is equivalent to SHOUTING! Thanks.

Comment: `s.containsVowel(...)` -- `s` is `String` and `containsVowel` is a method. What are you trying to do? AFAIK, string class does not have a method called `containsVowel` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: not with my Programing LAB all it says is You seem to have an error in compilation.  thats it

Comment: sorry about that dont mean to be shouting

Comment: @AlorvaEx: just use a standard Java compiler then.

Comment: I am My programming lab uses a Java complier without the need of the rest of the codeing

Comment: But you're not getting the descriptive error message that is the most informative part of the error. As if you didn't know there was an error when it wouldn't compile!

Comment: the first line of your method calls istelf recursivly, and *discards* the original input string.

Comment: Let me add another My Programing lab question and answer so you get an idea of how this website wants answers

Comment: @Alorva Ex If you want detailed compiler errors, set up and use your own IDE to compile, test and debug your code on, such as Netbeans or Eclipse.

Comment: Note that your style of programming could benefit by greatly if you would compile your code very frequently, perhaps after adding only 1 or 2 lines, and then not add any new code until you fix your current code and it compiles correctly. This technique should help you avoid ending up with a rat's nest of a hundred errors.

Comment: I wish I could do that but when using http://www.myprogramminglab.com/ its more difficult to do so.

Comment: @Alorva Ex You are very confused. It is not difficult to download Netbeans and test your code in Netbeans, before going to myprogramminglab.com when it fully compiles and works as tested by you, for example.

Comment: @Alorva Ex By the way, the example you posted for the other recursive question from your site is very similar to what you should write for the question you are on.

Comment: I dont even have access to the rest of the code or what the string actually has thats already done by the myprogramming lab.  all the want is (from what im told} a simple code that answers the question without the normal coding process when using Net beans

Comment: @Alorva Ex You don't need access to the rest of the code in this case, because all it's going to do is call your method with strings. So, for example, you could make a java class Main in Netbeans, write a method `public static void main(String[] args)` which calls `containsVowel()` with different strings, printing the result, to test if it works or not.

Comment: Also I have NetBeans and I have tried using Netbeans first and then copying the answer to myprogramming lab multiple times and they have never wprked.

Comment: @Alorva Ex In what way did they not work? Code that solves a problem solves the problem in the same way no matter where it is compiled. It cannot magically change its functionality.

Comment: Build a driver for your program. A simple program that is an interface to the code you'll be putting on the site. Once you validated it paste the code in question onto the site. Setting up your own project in NetBeans is too easy for that to be your excuse.

Comment: let me start over with this code.  First it is asking to for a boolean value.  If I am correct in NetBeans u could say boo Vowel = String "s" right

Comment: @Alorva Ex No, because that is not a valid Java statement. (That is. you could not write that in any Java in any context.)

Comment: In my programming lab u have to say boolean Vowel = String "s" thats a simple change and difference there are far more complex differences than that.

Comment: I see then okay then back to square 1 drawing board

Comment: @Alorva Ex `bool` does not exist in Java. `boolean` however does. And lines that are not typed correctly, with the correct spelling, syntax (and sometimes capitalization) are not valid Java, so neither of those lines will compile.

Comment: if u notice the first answer down below saying that I need to add a public static method, Yes in net beans for Java its required.  In my programming lab they don't want all they want is the very specific code like my above second question and answer anyhting else is deemed wrong and wont work.

Comment: @Alorva Ex Yes, that is correct - in a standalone program, you need a method with signature `public static void main(String[] args)`. However, the presence of this method will have zero effect on how you code `containsVowel(String s)`, as all your `main` will do is call `containsVowel()` a lot of times with different strings to change how it works - it is the testing, and `containsVowel(String s)` is the 'actual logic' that won't change from Netbeans to your programming lab.

Comment: let me put it this way everything except aeiouAEIOU is a required part of the answer if u take out say != the complier will say you need to be using != and mark it wrong

Comment: @Alorva Ex Ewww. That is disgusting. I suggest you find a better way to teach yourself Java :) I have nothing further to say.

Comment: None of that matters. [This](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_main_in_java) is a simple explanation about the static method you seem to be scared of. Basically what you will be doing is imitating what is provided for you by the site i.e., a way to call your method.

Comment: okay I am not scard of the static method I just finsihed writting a lab assignemnt requiring a static method through netbeans.  and even that is not helping me figure this problem out.

Comment: I have to go I am still getting over a headcold and now my headache and fevor has come back thanks for all the advice.  back to searching google for whats wrong

Comment: Your original statement was- compilier says that there is an error and it is not offering help- which is what you'd get from NetBeans. They do not provide you with verbose errors b/c they want you to figure it out. If you're saying that a valid answer must include the errors pointed out in the answers here, then see Patashu's last comment.

Answer (score 10):

This code has a few problems in it.

1. `s.containsVowel`.  `s` is a String and the Java String doesn't have a `containsVowel` method.  You should be calling your own `containsVowel` method instead, not that String one (that doesn't exist).
2. If you make that change, this will be an infinite recursive method because you don't have a "base case".  A case that makes it exit.
3. `(s.substring( !=));` does not compile.  I don't know what you're even trying to do here.
4. `return false` does not end with a semicolon.  It needs to if you want your code to compile.

Here's the way you should approach this algorithm in pseudocode

```
containsVowel(String input)
    if (empty(input)) return false  //the base case
    char firstChar = getFirstCharOf(input)
    return firstChar.isAnyOf("vowelCharacters") || containsVowel(inputWithoutFirstChar(input))
```

Comment: Also of note: his `containsVowel` method isn't static, so he either needs to declare it as static or call it on an instance of whatever class this belongs to. +1 for everything, especially the pseudocode (I might use "or" instead of `||`)

Comment: +1 for point number three. Made my afternoon.

Comment: and for thats where u cant do it in mt programming lab

Comment: when u use my programming lab u skip everything that u would write in netbeans and just write the actually method that is need look above at my second question and answer.

Comment: @Alorva Ex So, write the extra stuff you would write so you can compile and test in Netbeans... Then copy over only the specific part your programming lab expects. This way you will get the detailed compiler error feedback of Netback, a better ability to test your own code, you can use the debugger, etc. and you can still use your programming lab when you're satisfied personally with how your code works. I don't see what the problem is with this tactic.

Comment: I have tried it multiple times and could never get it to work after it work on netbeans for many differnet problems.

Answer (score 3):

Let's just throw out this code and start from base principles. (My one remark for the code you had is that programs must be written EXACTLY how the language expects them to be written - programs are not mind readers, they do not know what you want, they only know what you typed, and things like `(s.substring(!=));` are 100% meaningless, even if it makes perfect sense in your head.)

---

The idea of a recursive method is that it has a base case and a repetition condition.

The base case for containsVowel is the empty string, "" - return false.

The repetition condition is if the current character is not a vowel, we return true, else we call containsVowel with the string one character shorter. This way every character is checked until we find a vowel, and if we run out of characters (base case) we abort.

You can check if the current character is a vowel by looking at `s.charAt(0)` and using `indexOf` to see if it is contained in `"aeiouAEIOU"`.

You can call yourself on the string one shorter by doing `return containsVowel(s.substring(1));` (which creates a string out of `s` starting at the second character, e.g. one shorter)

Can you see how to write the method now?

Answer (score 0):

Lines in java end with a semicolon. You seem to be missing one.

```
return false
```

Answer (score 0):

- `containsVowel()` is not a valid method for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).
- Statements end in semi-colons (so `return false` becomes `return false;`
- `s.substring(!=)` is a syntax error, since `!=` is not a valid symbol.
- `s.substring()` creates a new `String`, and you're not capturing the result of that (after the corrected symbol, of course) in any variable.

There's an easier way to decipher if a String has a vowel - it involves regular expressions, the set of vowels you want to check (what about the word fly?), and can be verified using [a graphical regex checker](http://debuggex.com).  I'll leave this portion as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: It's homework, so the answer has to be recursive.

Comment: I did say that a regex-based way was *easier*, not what the requirements prescribed.  At least now I understand what that bare `s.substring()` was for, though.

Comment: yeah if u take out that code then nothing will be right cause the complier will say you need to be using substring!